# How to calculate brightness histogram?

Tags: opencv, histogram, emgucv

I have a Hue histogram for a specific image, as depicted in the following graph:

[image]

Here is the code that I use for calculating the Hue histogram (I'm using the EMGU wrapper):

```
   Image<Hsv, Byte> hsvImage = originalImage.Convert<Hsv, Byte>();
   Image<Gray, byte>[] channels = hsvImage.Split();    
   DenseHistogram hist = new DenseHistogram(19, new RangeF(0,190));
   hist.Calculate(new IImage[1] { channel }, true, null);
```

I need to get the brightness histogram for the pixels which are located within the range between the red dotted lines.

Dos anyone have any ideas on how to implement this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `channel` declared as? Is it merely a placeholder for the channel you wish to plot?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [InRange](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/07eff70b-f81f-6313-98a9-02d508f7c7e0.htm) to get an image which is a mask of the pixels which fall into the range you desire. Then pass that image as the `mask` parameter (which is `null` in your example) to `Calculate()`. It looks like you want hue values between 70 and 100.

The code might look like this: (Disclaimer: I don't write C#)

```
DenseHistogram brightnessHist = new DenseHistogram(10, new RangeF(0,260)); //Use whatever range you want
//InRange is probably exclusive of upper bound
brightnessHist.Calculate(new IImage[1]{channels[2]}, false, channels[0].InRange(70,101));
```

Comment: Aurelies ,any idea how can I desplay the result of brightnessHist?

Comment: I would assume the same way you display the other histograms.